# LLVM assembly string constant syntax

Tags: string, syntax, constants, llvm

I have a few questions about the LLVM assembly string constant syntax. The syntax that I am referring to is this:

```
@helloWorldString = private constant [13 x i8] c"hello world\0A\00"
```

In particular I am talking about the `c"hello world\0A\00"` form.

I have two questions:

1) Where is this syntax documented?

2) How can I split a long string constant into several lines?

Comment: You can always look at the [llvm source code](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/LLLexer_8cpp_source.html#l00330). It doesn't seems `2)` is possible. It only allows [basic escape sequences](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/LLLexer_8cpp_source.html#l00141).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't documented, but `c"hello world\0A\00"` pretty much demonstrates the complete extent of the syntax.  There's no way to split the string into multiple lines.  There really isn't any careful documentation of the syntax because it's it's pretty straightforward, and there's only one parser.